# Django Error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: after inserting {% providers_media_js %}

Tags: python, django, facebook

I m preparing a Django Application where I need to have a Facebook Auth and process various data from the facebook posts. So I am first trying to authorize using the `AllAuth` library of `Django`.

I have followed the process from the blog: https://medium.com/@jinkwon711/django-allauth-facebook-login-b536444cbc6b.

Now I after running I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError at /
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'WebsiteIP:port'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://WebsiteIP:port/
Django Version: 1.11.5
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'WebsiteIP:port'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 966
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.12
Python Path:    
['/home/ubuntu/PersonalityWithFacebook',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 9 Oct 2017 08:19:13 +0000
```

This problem started when I have inserted the code:

```
{% load socialaccount %}
{% providers_media_js %}
```

If I remove just this single line the website is up but not function-able:

```
{% providers_media_js %}
```

So kindly, let me know what I am missing.

Here is the complete trace of teh error:
https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/a053e133474472c02f7507c634f7387c

Comment: Do you use '`WebsiteP:port`' as the actual address in your browser and you are not accessing your site locally via sth. like `'127.0.0.1:8000'`?

Comment: actually I used 0.0.0.0:4000 as the website port address. on website  I see my actual address. I do mean to reveal it for some secrecy. but iff you want then I willpaste the IP:port.